# Hubproxy.On not firing after a long time

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I have a wpf application which use SignalR HubConnection. everything works as expected. But after a long time (for example 10 hours) hubproxy.on method not firing, server sending data to client correctly also hubproxy.Invoke works correctly, **only hubproxy.On does not work**. There is no connection error or disconnected state. It happens on Production environment

> Here is my client code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private IHubProxy hubProxy;
            private HubConnection connection;
            private string url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeConnection();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeConnection()
        {
            connection = new HubConnection(url);
            hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRHub");
            connection.StateChanged += connection_StateChanged;
            hubProxy.On<string>("OnMessage", OnMMessage);
            connection.Start();
        }

        void connection_StateChanged(StateChange obj)
        {
            if (obj.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                InitializeConnection();
            }
        }

        private void OnMMessage(string message)
        {
            //This not works sometimes
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this works always, is being logged on the server
            hubProxy.Invoke("SendMessage2", new object[1] { "dfdfdf" });
        }
    }
```

> this is server side

```
public class SignalRHub : Hub
{
    public Logger logger = new Logger();
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        SubscriberCache.Subscribers.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public void UnSubscribe()
    {
        if (SubscriberCache.Subscribers.Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
            SubscriberCache.Subscribers.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        UnSubscribe();
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        if (!SubscriberCache.Subscribers.Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
            SubscriberCache.Subscribers.Add(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        //this works always
        logger.Info("message sending to client");
        Clients.All.OnMessage(message);

    }
}
```